# Enable scroll in .md-scroll-mask

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-material

In a web app I'm using AngularJS and Angular Material. The problem is that when I open some component - as md-select, or md-autocomplete - it add a div with class md-scroll-mask, that prevent the scrolling of the whole page. How can I enable the scrolling of the page?